# Capture output of double-ssh (ssh twice) session as BASH variable

Tags: bash, ssh

I'd like to capture the output of an ssh session. However, I first need to ssh **twice** (from my local computer to the remote portal to the remote server), then run a command and capture the output.

Doing this line-by-line, I would do:

```
ssh name@remote.portal.com
ssh remote.server.com
remote.command.sh
```

I have tried the following:

```
server=remote.server.com  ##define in the script, since it varies
sshoutput=$(ssh -tt name@remote.portal.com exec "ssh -tt ${server} echo \"test\"")
echo $sshoutput
```

I would expect the above script to echo "test" after the final command. However, the outer ssh prompt just hangs after I enter my command and, once I Ctrl+c or fail to enter my password, the inner ssh session fails (I believe since stdout is no longer printed to screen and I no longer get my password prompt).

If I run just the inner command (i.e., without "sshoutput=$(" to save it as a variable), then it works but (obviously) does not capture output. I have also tried without the "exec".

I have also tried saving the inner ssh as a variable like

```
sshoutput=$(ssh -tt name@portal myvar=$(ssh -tt ${server} echo \"test\"") && echo $myvar)
```

but that fails because BASH tries to execute the inner ssh before sending it to the outer ssh session (I believe), and the server name is not recognized.

(I have looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89428/ssh-twice-in-bash-alias-function but they simply say "more flags required if using interactive passwords" and do not address capturing output)

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: The best approach here, by far, is to use `ProxyCommand` to have ssh itself do the work of setting up the inner ssh session.

Comment: Why are you using `-tt`? I'm not sure it makes a difference to this question, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @ ProxyCommand comment: something like the below link?  My above remote.command.sh actually sets up a VNC server and returns which port (e.g., ":3") to use, then I ssh tunnel to that port.  Will the commands in the below link interfere (and/or not have permission) with that?     http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/

Comment: @cwotta, please include enough content to generate and test an answer *in your question itself*, as opposed to behind a link (particularly behind a cyberciti.biz link; I wouldn't touch that with a 10-foot pole). That said, in general, `ProxyCommand` usage doesn't interfere with other kinds of SSH proxy support.

Comment: @ why -tt: It appeared, through looking various sites, that it was necessary since I was double-ssh-ing.  I would receive "not a real terminal"-type error (can't remember specifically), but it appears that it's no longer an issue because I just tested without it and it's no longer there, though my commands fail to execute.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry about the external link, fair enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best-practice approach here is to have ssh itself do the work of jumping through your bouncehost.

```
result=$(ssh \
  -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh name@remote.portal.com nc -w 120 %h %p' \
  name@remote.server.com \
  "remote.command.sh")
```

You can automate that in your `~/.ssh/config`, like so:

```
Host remote.server.com
    ProxyCommand ssh name@remote.portal.com nc -w 120 %h %p
```

...after which any `ssh remote.server.com` command will automatically jump through `remote.portal.com`. (Change `nc` to `netcat` or similar, as appropriate for tools that are installed on the bouncehost).

---

That said, if you *really* want to do it yourself, you can:

```
printf -v inner_cmd '%q ' "remote.command.sh"
printf -v outer_cmd '%q ' ssh name@remote.server.com "$inner_cmd"
ssh name@remote.portal.com bash -s <<EOF
$outer_cmd
EOF
```

...the last piece of which can be run in a command substitution like so:

```
result=$(ssh name@remote.portal.com bash -s <<EOF
$outer_cmd
EOF
)
```

Comment: And if you always need to use the proxy to get to that remote server, you can put it into your `.ssh/config`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- Update: I was incorrect.  I'm using the first code block.  It's NOT capturing the output into $result, it's just printing it to the screen (stdout) -- I initially thought it worked because I was echoing $result after, to check -- otherwise, it works (i.e., I'm able to log in and execute the command).  Additionally, I tried the final two code blocks and immediately received three "permission denied" errors.  This isn't important to fix, since I am not using that method, but thought I would note it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the first code block **as edited**? The first version didn't capture at all (that was left as a -- rather obvious -- exercise to the reader).

Comment: ...if it's still not capturing, chances are good that the content you're trying to grab are actually going to stderr, not stdout. Put a `2>&1` before the closing paren of the command substitution.

Comment: ...as for the permission denied errors, use `set -x` to log the exact commands being run locally, and change `bash -s` to `bash -x -s` to do likewise for the remote bits. And post the output. I wouldn't be surprised if you had `"remote.command.sh 'argument 1' 'argument 2'"` when it needs to be `"remote.command.sh" 'argument 1' 'argument 2'` passed to printf, or similar; should be obvious when given the logs.

Comment: ssh name@remote.server.com 'remote.command.sh\ -geometry\ 2800x750\ -depth\ 8\ -pixelformat\ BGR233\ 2\>\&1 '

Must be difference in printf --- I'm on Mac so BSD.  All single quotes (even though double in the code, as you have above).  Again, I'm not personally concerned about getting this to work for MY case.  If you want to continue debugging for others' sake, that's fine with me.

Comment: @cwotta, ...if you have arguments, they should be passed as separate arguments to printf, not as part of a single string. `printf -v inner_command '%q ' remote.command.sh -geometry 2800x750 -depth 8 -pixelformat BGR233` -- note the lack of a `2>&1` there. The advantage of using `printf '%q '` here is that if you have arguments with literal whitespace in them (you don't!) you can pass them inside double quotes to printf and they'll be held together as individual arguments in the generated command.

Comment: @cwotta, ...and this is using the bash-builtin printf, not `/usr/bin/printf`, so it's actually not different between platforms.